# selenium get the next element

Tags: python, selenium

i get a list of elements by using this code

```
allfreetoContact = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.listing_contactable")
```

and i use this code to click and send message, but it seem like just send to a "Element" in several times.

```
for elem in allfreetoContact:
 elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("listing_contactable").click()
 elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("primary-standard").click()
 mess = driver.find_element_by_name("message")
 mess.send_keys("Hi there")
 elem = driver.find_element_by_name("Submit").click()
 elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav_level2_a").click()
```

so,  how can i select the next element in the list in python???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("listing_contactable").click()
```

is telling the driver to pull a brand new list of elements (find_element_by_class_name) & click on the first one in the list instead of iterating through the list you already created.

Here is an example of how to click on every element in a list of elements using a for loop:

```
allfreetoContact = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.listing_contactable")
for elem in allfreetoContact:
     driver.elem.click()
```

Also, because you want your script to immediately execute the commands click or send keys instead of storing information, you don't need to create variables. Avoid re-using "elem =" and "mess =" in this case, since creating unnecessary variables increases your chances of making a mistake in the code and makes it harder to read.

```
for elem in allfreetoContact:
 driver.elem.click()
 driver.find_element_by_class_name("primary-standard").click()
 driver.find_element_by_name("message").send_keys("Hi there")
 driver.find_element_by_name("Submit").click()
 driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav_level2_a").click()
```